# How to disable dojox.grid.DataGrid

Tags: dojo

How can I disable dojox.grid.DataGrid. By disable I mean the whole widget should be disabled and not just some aspect of it (sorting,cell selection etc)

Answer (score 0):

You may try with a `dojox.widget.Standby` as explained here: [Loading indicator with dojo XHR requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7601079/loading-indicator-with-dojo-xhr-requests) .
I have never used it on a `dojox.grid.DataGrid` but it should work...

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean a READ-ONLY grid;
In creation of the grid:

```
 var dataGrid = new  dojox.grid.DataGrid({
                        id: 'xxx',
                        store: myStore, structure:myLayout,
                        canSort:false, //disable sorting //Then do the same thing for every attributes options and disable them all
                        }, dojo.byId("myDivName"));
```

You might have to override some default behavior such as:

```
        onHeaderEvent: function (e) {
           //make it do nothing                 

        },
```

and check on other events from http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojox/grid/DataGrid
just clear everything out.

And in your css, you might have to do such thing like:

```
.dojoxGridRowSelected
{
    background-color:none;
    border:none;.....
}

.dojoxGridCellFocus 
{
    border:none;
}
```

Just find the class names from your domNodes

Answer (score 0):

Use attribute "canSort : false" to hide or disable sort button in Dojo DataGrid code

var newGrid = new DataGrid({

```
    id : 'newGrid',

    canSort:false,

    store : this.resultStore,

    structure : this.resultGridLayout,

    autoHeight:true
```

});

Regards,

Satish M Hiremath