# Loading indicator with dojo XHR requests

Tags: dojo, xmlhttprequest

I only recently started using dojo and I am doing numerous ajax calls using dojo xhrGet, xhrPost,..etc. Now I have an animated gif image which i want to use to indicate "loading" to the user. I am not too sure how this can be done. Can someone please advise me on this? here is my code,

```
dojo.xhrGet({
                url: registcarturl,
                handleAs: "json",
                preventCache: true,
                load: function(data, ioArgs) {
                    //DO STUFF WITH data HERE
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    alert("sorry ! an error occurred while adding to the cart with ajax");
                }    
           });
```

How do i get my loading gif file into the interaction? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at `dojox.widget.Standby`: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/widget/Standby.html

To give you an example, define the `widget.Standby`

```
<div jsId="basicStandby1" dojoType="dojox.widget.Standby" target="yourDomTarget">
```

After calling `dojo.xhrGet`, show it:

```
 basicStandby1.show();
```

And when you receive your answer, hide it:

```
basicStandby1.hide();
```